# The tags around exams, homework and alike, how should they be structured?

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment there is already a small zoo of tags around these subjects; sometimes it is not quite clear to me what if any should be the difference (of course not for all tags below, I just wanted a it is hoped complete list to start sketching out the structure).

Here is a possibly incomplete list of the tags I have in mind.

- [exams](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exams) (plus [oral-exams](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral-exams), [closed-book-exams](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed-book-exams)),
- [homework](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework),
- [test-design](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-design),
- [problem-design](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-design),
- [grading](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading),
- [testing](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing),
- [placement](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placement),
- [assesement](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assesement)

To be clear, I do not want to "shoot down" anything. But, it is quite frustrating to have too similar tags where then questions are "split" over several tags.

Comment: Sorry to those that noticed for posting to main in error! What a disgrace... :( The *beta* was too similar to meta.

Comment: I think, this question can only tell you **if** there is some problem. If so, there should be more smaller questions dealing with part of it to decide.

Comment: @MarkusKlein I would say let us see what is said. To break it up in smaller questions has the issue that things depend on other decisions.

Answer (score 2):

- I would say, [exams](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exams), [homework](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) and [grading](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading) are fine and no one should be confused. I think, there are questions where they can stand alone, but most likely they are coupled with another tag. I don't think that it is too bad to have such "big" tags standing for themselves with many question in it.
- There are two ways to look at an exam: Before it is written and after it is written (maybe also the phase during the exam). [grading](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading) is fine for the aftermath, but there should be something for the creation (here, [test-design](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-design), [problem-design](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-design) are maybe similar; maybe they both should replaced by something else).
- A similar thing should hold for homework to distinguish between general issues (cheating, scheduling, motivation, etc.) and topic-based issues about the actual exercises.
- However, one might want to specify [exams](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exams) like [oral-exams](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral-exams). If we decide to do so, then the question is, if [exams](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exams) should be replaced with [exam-general-question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exam-general-question) (but a better title than this!). We should avoid having questions tagged with [exams](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exams) **as well as** [oral-exams](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral-exams).
- I'm not sure what is meant by [placement](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placement) and [assesement](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assesement). But they only appear once and should in my opinion be deleted.
- I'm not sure what is meant by [testing](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing) although it was used quite a few times. I think, it can be replaced by something else, but I'm not sure with what.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer; some of what you say is very much in line with my opinion. I agree with first point. I am not sure if you mean to  suggest "exam" is necessarily *written* it seems so in the second point, but I am not sure; could you clarify this please.

Comment: @quid Good question. When I wrote all this, I taught about "exam" as an generic term for written and oral exams. But the more I think about it, there is really a difference and only few (if any) questions consider general exams.